# Como puedo hacer que un calendario datepicker siga a un formulario fijo

Tags: css, css3, wordpress, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

tengo este problema de diseño.
Resulta que tengo un sitio web desarrollado con wordpress, utilizo para las reservas un plugins llamado formcraft y le he integrado una librería para los calendarios llamada datepicker.

¿Como puedo hacer que el calendario se quede fijo o siga al formulario de reserva, tengo el formulario de reserva con la propiedad sticky (CSS).

Muestro captures:
[image: ASÍ SE MUESTRA CUANDO ESTA FIJO]

[image: Y ASÍ SE MUESTRA EL PROBLEMA, EL CALENDARIO SUBE Y NO SE FIJA CON EL FORMULARIO]

Disculpen mi ignorancia.

Answer (score 1):

Mejor agrega este  plugin: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-menu-or-anything-on-scroll/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a tu `WORDPRESS` y ya solo a tu GRID en donde esta el FORMULARIO, le pones la clase del plugin STICKY MENU y listo, ya queda bien.

Espero te haya servido la información

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. He utilizado este plugin pero tiene errores de visualización en algunos casos, como por ejemplo da algunos saltos raros al moverse el calendario. intenté hacerlo con css y me funcionó hasta cierto punto, es decir, se mantiene fijo y sigue al calendario pero al subir el calendario llega hasta arriba.